# How to get a stream from SignalR input (client to server)

Tags: c#, stream, signalr

I have a stream that allows bi-directional communication between a terminal on the other side of it (it uses websockets). I got inputs working on a console app by using:
`_ = Console.OpenStandardInput().CopyToAsync(stream).ConfigureAwait(false);` Now i want the same but using the input from a client to my signalR hub. I tried using a static Stream instance and writing to that from a seperate method:

```
public ContainerStreams containerStream { get; }

        public ContainerShellHub(ContainerStreams container)
        {
            containerStream = container;
        }
        public async Task SendMessage(string message)
        {
            var sw = new StreamWriter(containerStream.Stream);

            sw.WriteLine(message);
            sw.Flush();

        }
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetLogs(
         string clusterId,
         [EnumeratorCancellation]
         CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            ...
          var websocket =
           await client.WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync(pod.Metadata.Name, "default", "sh",
               pod.Spec.Containers[0].Name);
          var demux = new StreamDemuxer(websocket);
          demux.Start();

           var stream = demux.GetStream(ChannelIndex.StdOut, ChannelIndex.StdIn);
            _ = containerStream.Stream.CopyToAsync(stream).ConfigureAwait(false);

            ... 
         }
```

This however does not work, i cannot find a way to get my users inputs into the stream